# Entity framework PostgreSQL

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql

Can someone tell me how can I get MS Entity Framework working with PostgreSQL.

Also: How does Entity Framewok work with Mono? Could you please suggest other similar ORM tools which would run on Mono and what is your opinion about them?

Comment: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/wiki/Entity-Framework

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Entity framework also works with Npgsql - .Net Data Provider for Postgresql.
A tutorial on how to set it up can be found here:
http://www.npgsql.org/ef6/index.html

Comment: Github page https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql  (the above url is currently unreachable for me)

Comment: The [Npgsql Entity Framework Core provider for PostgreSQL](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL) is now hosted in a separate GitHub repo (as is the [EF5/6 Npgsql provider](https://github.com/npgsql/EntityFramework6.Npgsql)).  There is also a [EF Core Getting Started page on npgsql.org](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/) with documentation.

Answer (score 11):

Devart has a product that gives entity framework support for PostgreSQL. See:

http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/

There is a provider for mono for postgreSQL. See:

http://www.mono-project.com/PostgreSQL