# How do set up PostgreSQL + entity framweork?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql

The npgsql ado.net provider claims to support the entity framework.

Is there any documentation/guide how to set this up, and get me jump started here ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this stackoveflow question
[Entity framework PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211475/entity-framework-postgresql)

You may have more luck using [NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html) with [NHibernate Linq](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQToNHibernate.ashx) with PostgreSQL