# Can you use Microsoft Entity Framework with Postgres?

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql

Well, there is similar question for Oracle, now, Postgres?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity framework PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211475/entity-framework-postgresql)

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework is designed to be database agnostic. It doesn't use any SQL Server feature, and doesn't natively support things as the Geometry features of SQL Server.

You won't be able to use any feature specific to Postgres (but you can write your Entity Framework extensions to do it, however)

But the point is: It will work.