# Performing Insert and Update on a DataTable using LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, visual-studio-2010

I am pretty new to using LINQ and have been trying it out querying my strongly typed DataTable.
I have managed to perform a '`Select`' ok but was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction to do `Insert` and `Updates`. I'm not sure if LINQ is best doing an insert at all?

My Select code is as follows:

```
Dim results = From myRow In _dt.AsEnumerable() _
                      Where myRow.Language_key = Lang And _
                      myRow.Section_key = SectionKey And _
                      myRow.Message_number = MsgNum _
                      Select myRow.Message_line_1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Linq`

1. *L* : Langauge
2. *IN*: Integerated
3. *Q* : Query

it is for querying collections like `DataTable` not for doing `Insert` or `Update`

if you want to do that you can use `LinqToSql` or use `Entity framework`

Comment: I believe that I can only use LinqToSql with SQL Server?

Comment: yes but you can use this open source project http://code2code.net/DB_Linq/ to use it with `mysql`.you can use `Entity framework` for with any `RDBMS` like `oracle` and `mysql`.

Comment: ...But not Pervasive PSQL using ODBC which is what I am stuck using :-(

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211475/entity-framework-postgresql