# mySql and .net desktop applications

Tags: .net, mysql, database

after doing some research i'm still not sure if using mysql with .net desktop apps is the right choice. most tutorials for mysql are explained with php and mention that this DB in mainly used in web applications, but the SQL server alternative is either size limited (express version) or quite expensive. 
i tried this nice tutorial: http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/12/09/getting-mysql-work-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx and created a small WPF + Entity framework application that seems to work nice but i would be happy if someone with more experience in this could give me some advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "desktop app", do you mean that the database is "private" to one instance of the application, or that there are several application instances "talking" to the same database (potentially over the network)?

If the *former* is the case, what you really need is an "embedded" database. There are several  options, including:

- [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx),
- [SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx) (a deplyment option of [SQL Server 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx)),
- [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/),
- [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/fbmetasecur-embedded.html) or [Interbase](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/interbase/product-editions),
- [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/overview/index.html),
- etc...

You could of course also use a client-server DBMS in that scenario, but you'd have to consider whether this might be "too powerful" for your needs, and put unnecessary administration burden on your customers.

If the *latter* is the case, then you definitely need a "real" client-server DBMS.

Comment: thanks for your reply, what i meant is indeed the client - server DB. does a MySQL DB supports this scenario?

Comment: @Yoav Yes, MySQL supports client-server model. Please beware that every DBMS has its pros and cons and MySQL is no different, so you might want to take a look at some more options before you make the final decision. Some **free** client-server DBMSes: ProstgreSQL ([apparently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2585434/533120), it also supports the .NET entity framework, if that's important to you), Firebird, MS SQL Server Express, Oracle Express, DB2 Express-C. Or, even consider one of the "big" commercial DBMSes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Branko, looks like the PostgreSQL will be my preferred choice.