# What choices of ORM allow for near 'flick a switch' to change RDBMS between...SQL Server / SQL Azure and PostgreSQL / 'Cloud' PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, postgresql, orm

Given the following constraints:

- I will develop a BRAND NEW website.
- I will use C# and ASP.NET MVC
- Linux with mono would be good, but windows is an acceptable constraint (please mention if it is).

**Now the interesting bit:**

- I want to get as close as possible to being able to **'flick a switch'** to change RDBMS between SQL Server / SQL Azure and PostgreSQL / Cloud based PostgreSQL.
- I want to take advantage of an ORM as much as possible (the ORM MUST ***IDEALLY*** require little more than changing a setting to switch to one of these alternative database backend).
- This should include calling stored procedures in the same way with all.

For the interest of many, I am looking for OPTIONS with detailed limitations from hands on experience.

- Please do **NOT** give answers like "not possible" or "don't bother".
- Please do **NOT** compare ORMs in any other way than their ability to do the above and how much of their functionality is retained. This should **NOT** turn into x ORM is better than y ORM.
- Please do **NOT** discuss limitations of SQL Azure vs dedicated hosting.
- Please do **NOT** discuss SQL Server or PostgreSQL differences, strengths/weaknesses, stored procedure conversion, etc.
- Please do **NOT** discuss what should be in stored procedures and what should be in  service layers.

Comment: That's a lot of rules for answering your question.

Comment: Yes... to keep the focus on the question.  I know it's a bit full on. :-)

Comment: I came across two similar questions:  [Mentions Nhibernate and Dataobjects ORM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449086/asp-net-mvc-with-postgres-orm-recommendations).  [Entity framework Specific](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211475/entity-framework-postgresql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb399567.aspx) supports your requirements. It can definitely [connect to both of your providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565.aspx). It looks like you can use stored procs, too, but that's a little fuzzy.

I believe the only "switch" you flip is in the `.config` file (no rebuild).

As an aside in case it's relevant, the new EF Code First + Migrations bits are pretty neat. I've been using them with SQL Server locally for development and a SQL Server cloud host for production. I've been very happy with them.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of devart, but not virtuoso and PgFoundry providers.  I will upvote your answer, but I will not mark as accepted...hopefully someone else can provide more detailed information.  Your statement starting "I believe" leaves me still unsure. When the time comes (if no other answer) I guess I may try a simple project with a few tables and try switching between these providers.  I have not used Entity Framework yet so I don't know any better.

Comment: Marked as answered, I have investigated further.  I like the look of the following Micro ORMs: Peta-Poco Dapper, ORM-Lite for performance reasons but I might to well to use EF5 intially for scaffolding/RAD reasons.