# Visual Studio Entity Framework connect to Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-4.1, database-connection

I want to connect to a Postgres database using EntityFramework. Is that possible?

I select:

> Add>>New Item>>ADO.Net Entity Data model>>Generate from database>>New
>   connection

But I'm stuck there. I need to generate classes for the tables in the database.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution to use PostgreSQL in combination with Entity Framework is the dotConnect provider from Devart.

You can find the PostgreSQL provider here:

http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql

Answer (score 3):

The following question:

[Entity framework PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211475/entity-framework-postgresql)

is extremely similar to yours, and covers the same ground. You will see references to npgsql there, and to Devart.