# FSharp data type provider for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, f#, npgsql, type-providers, f#-3.0

I was trying FSharp data provider but against the Postgresql using npgsql. And I busted at very first line.

When I am trying to create SqlDataConnection it is throwing error with message the connection string is not correct.

> The type provider
>   'Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DesignTime.DataProviders'
>   reported an error: Keyword not supported: 'port:5432;database'.

Now, I test connection string and also data using Servicestack.Ormlite. That basically uses IdbConnection. So, connection is all correct. But I don't know why Type Provider is not working.

Here is code.

```
    //type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=5432; Database=TestDB;User Id=postgres;Password=g00gle*92;" >
[<CLIMutable>]
type Person = 
    { ID : int;
      FirstName : string;
      LastName : string }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = 
    let dbFactory = 
        OrmLiteConnectionFactory
            (
             "Server=localhost;Port=5432; Database=TestDB;User Id=postgres;Password=*****;", 
             PostgreSqlDialect.Provider)
    use dbConnection = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection()
    Console.WriteLine dbConnection.State
    let persons = dbConnection.Select<Person>()
    persons.ForEach(fun p -> Console.WriteLine p.FirstName)
    Console.Read() |> ignore
    0
```

In above code first commented line is not working while with same settings below code is working. That means issue is only with type provider not with connections IMHO.

Do I need to do any other settings.

Please let me know if any other details are required.

**UPDATE**

After kvb's comment I tried both. Here is updated code with web config.

```
//type dbSchema = SqlEntityConnection<ConnectionStringName = "TestDB", Provider="Npgsql">
    type dbSchema = SqlEntityConnection< ConnectionStringName="TestDB" >

    [<CLIMutable>]
    type Person = 
        { ID : int;
          FirstName : string;
          LastName : string }

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main args = 
        let dbFactory = 
            OrmLiteConnectionFactory
                (
                 "Server=localhost;Port=5432; Database=TestDB;User Id=postgres;Password=*******;", 
                 PostgreSqlDialect.Provider)
        use dbConnection = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection()
        Console.WriteLine dbConnection.State
        let persons = dbConnection.Select<Person>()
        persons.ForEach(fun p -> Console.WriteLine p.FirstName)
        Console.Read() |> ignore
        0
```

And here is web config

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider"
            invariant="Npgsql"
            description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL"
            type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestDB"
          connectionString="Server=localhost:5432; Database=TestDB;User Id=postgres;Password=******;"
          providerName="Npgsql" />

  </connectionStrings>
```

and here is assembly in appconfig. I don't think it will be in GAC as I added via nuget

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.12.0" newVersion="2.0.12.0" />
 </dependentAssembly>
```

Above both one is commented and another one without which is not commented both is failing with different error.
First one is failing with error

> The type provider
>   'Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DesignTime.DataProviders'
>   reported an error: Error reading schema. error 7001: The specified
>   store provider 'Npgsql' cannot be found in the configuration, or
>   'Npgsql' is not valid. Unable to find the requested .Net Framework
>   Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

and second one is with this error

> The type provider
>   'Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DesignTime.DataProviders'
>   reported an error: Error reading schema. error 7001: The provider did
>   not return a ProviderManifestToken string. A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server) The network path was not
>   found

I still not understand why it is searching for SQL server.

Please let me know if any further infromation required.

Comment: It seems odd that you have `Port:5432` but all other values are in the form `key=value`

Comment: @JohnPalmer thanks for pointing out typo. It is giving same issue. And if I tried localhost:5432 directly it still unable to connect the server.

Comment: The `SqlDataConnection` relies on [sqlmetal.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx) for its codegen, which only supports SQL Server as far as I know.

Comment: @kvb then what I should do to add other database ?

Comment: You could try using `SqlEntityConnection` instead, since the Entity Framework does support multiple databases.  I don't know the specifics of how to configure it, but see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211475/entity-framework-postgresql for some more information about using PostgreSQL with Entity Framework.

Comment: @kvb did that... Still not working. Still it is going and trying to find SQL server provider. I don't know why. I am giving Postgres provider in connection string.

Comment: I think you probably need to set the type provider's `Provider` static parameter to the name of the Postgres provider's class.  E.g. for SQL Server this is `"System.Data.SqlClient"`, but the corresponding Postgres provider will probably depend on what library you use.

Comment: @kvb that I did in App.Config and in above code instead of connection string I am just giving connection string name. So, it is taking provider too. But no luck till now.
You think there is a need to create a new data provider all together???

Comment: I think that you may need to set the optional `Provider` parameter of the [`SqlEntityConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362322.aspx) _in addition to_ setting the connection string properly.

Comment: That is, `SqlEntityConnection<ConnectionStringName="...", Provider="...">`

Comment: @kvb I updated question. I tried your suggestions but still no luck.

Comment: I suspect that it's looking for SQL Server because the default provider is `"System.Data.SqlClient"` unless something else is specified.  Can you post the actual error you get when you try to specify the `"Npgsql"` provider?

Comment: @kvb I have updated the question with error message.

Comment: Is the `Npgsql` assembly in the GAC?  What happens if you use the full assembly name in the `type` section (including public key, etc.)?

Comment: @kvb I don't think it is there. As I added via nuget. Thanks for pointing out I have update question also.
You want me to change type section, as dependent assembly is there only. And simple NgplSQLConnection is working.

Comment: I'd suggest adding it to the GAC then, and seeing if that changes anything.  After that, I'm about out of ideas...

Comment: @kvb :( no luck. Same error. Anyways thanks for helping.

Comment: I gather then that it's not going to work with MySQL or any other non-Sql Server database -- maybe with Mono? They're usually a step or 2 behind M$ latest and greatest.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having exactly the same problem.

Comment: @user1888014 not with data type provider. I will be using dapper than. I think I have to wait or have to create my own type provider to support other databases. Lets see. Currently I fall back to using Micro Orms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to post a partial answer in the hope that someone can work out how to do the next bit.

The following code will compile:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open System.Data.Entity // this is important -- you cannot see any tables without it

type internal dbSchema = 
    SqlEntityConnection<
        ConnectionString="Server=localhost;Database=testdb;User Id=postgres;Password=password;", 
        Provider="Npgsql">

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let context = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
    query { for item in context.test_table do
            select item }
    |> Seq.iter (fun item -> printfn "%A" item)
    0
```

For a table `test_table` in database `testdb`  created via

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  value text,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_test_x_Id" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE test_table
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

To do this you need to do four things:

- GAC Npgsql.dll (`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe" /i [filename]`)
- GAC Mono.Security.dll (in the same directory that Npgsql.dll was downloaded to by NuGet
- Add the DbProviderFactory to your .NET 4 64-bit machine.config (`"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config"`): that is the same thing you have in your app.config, but added to the appropriate section in machine.config, mine has one entry at the moment for `Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider`. Remember to include the correct public key token.

> ```
> <system.data>
>   <DbProviderFactories>
>     <add name="Npgsql Data Provider"
>       invariant="Npgsql"
>       description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL"
>       type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=2.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />
> </DbProviderFactories>
> </system.data>
> ```

- Restart visual studio.

Now the `SqlEntityConnection` compile at design time and you will be able to see all of the tables that are available. This will also happily compile into an executable.

That answers your question; but now for the weird bit which will mean you are still not happy. When you run this code it will throw an `ArgumentException` as soon as `dbSchema.GetDataContext()` is called saying:

> The supplied connection string should be either a valid provider-specific connection string or a valid connection string accepted by the EntityClient.

The inner exception states

> The 'server' keyword is not supported.

with stack-trace

> at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>      at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
>      at SqlEntityConnection1.dbSchema.GetDataContext()

I've tried frigging the connection string to get it to work, but I think that this must be a bug in how the provider is creating the connection string at run-time vs design-time. Since this code is emitted into a dynamic assembly it isn't obvious how you could look at the code to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same difficulty. This is fixed by adding this in the App.config file :

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
</providers>
```